# Print sundays of a year with loops in java

Tags: java

I hope all of you are doing well.

Like I was saying in title, I'm trying to print sundays in java by only having the first day of the week of the year (let's say 1/1/2019 was a tuesday represented by the number 2)

Is there any way to do this without using calendar() or arrays? I mean, by using only for or while loops?

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Edit: some code

Hi @rainer I didn't saw your comment sorry for that. I've some code but is useless it only prints january sundays and now I'm a bit stuck.

```
    int monday = 1;
    int tuesday = 2;
    int wednesday = 3;
    int thursday = 4;
    int friday = 5;
    int saturday = 6;
    int sunday = 7;

    // Printing 2019 sundays for date: (tuesday) 1/1/2019

    for (int i = 1, month = 1, firstDayYear = tuesday; i <= 31 && month <= 12; i += 7) {

        if (month == 1) {
            if (firstDayYear == 1) {
                i += 6;
            } else if (firstDayYear == 2) {
                i += 5;
            } else if (firstDayYear == 3) {
                i += 4;
            } else if (firstDayYear == 4) {
                i += 3;
            } else if (firstDayYear == 5) {
                i += 2;
            } else if (firstDayYear == 6) {
                i += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sunday " + i);
        month++;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I am reviewing your post. You could add some code, to help community help you.

Comment: To answer your question, yes it's possible to list all Sundays in a calendar year without using any Java date classes.  You will need arrays to hold month names and the number of days in each month.  You have to create your own calendar and iterate through your own calendar.  The reason you're getting Jave date class answers is that the date classes do most of the calculations for you.  Good luck reinventing LocalDate.

Comment: No, without arrays or localdate. The idea was to use loops as practice for a proposed exercise but I am starting to think that it is a bit more complicated than I thought.

I believed that by nesting some for loops with if conditions it could iterate over 1 year days and show only the ones that are Sunday.

I don't need the "date" type itself, just an int number that represents sunday of year 1/1/2019.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: When asking a question for a school assignment, say so, to receive appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

To find the first Sunday of the year, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html), obtained from the factory class [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html).

For this, you can use [`firstInMonth(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-) or [`nextOrSame(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-), the result is the same.

*List all Sundays in 2019*

```java
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1)
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
//  OR  .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
LocalDate endDate = startDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextYear());

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);
for (LocalDate date = startDate; date.isBefore(endDate); date = date.plusDays(7))
    System.out.println(date.format(fmt));
```

*Output*

```
Sunday, January 6, 2019
Sunday, January 13, 2019
Sunday, January 20, 2019
Sunday, January 27, 2019
Sunday, February 3, 2019
Sunday, February 10, 2019
Sunday, February 17, 2019
Sunday, February 24, 2019
Sunday, March 3, 2019
Sunday, March 10, 2019
Sunday, March 17, 2019
Sunday, March 24, 2019
Sunday, March 31, 2019
Sunday, April 7, 2019
Sunday, April 14, 2019
Sunday, April 21, 2019
Sunday, April 28, 2019
Sunday, May 5, 2019
Sunday, May 12, 2019
Sunday, May 19, 2019
Sunday, May 26, 2019
Sunday, June 2, 2019
Sunday, June 9, 2019
Sunday, June 16, 2019
Sunday, June 23, 2019
Sunday, June 30, 2019
Sunday, July 7, 2019
Sunday, July 14, 2019
Sunday, July 21, 2019
Sunday, July 28, 2019
Sunday, August 4, 2019
Sunday, August 11, 2019
Sunday, August 18, 2019
Sunday, August 25, 2019
Sunday, September 1, 2019
Sunday, September 8, 2019
Sunday, September 15, 2019
Sunday, September 22, 2019
Sunday, September 29, 2019
Sunday, October 6, 2019
Sunday, October 13, 2019
Sunday, October 20, 2019
Sunday, October 27, 2019
Sunday, November 3, 2019
Sunday, November 10, 2019
Sunday, November 17, 2019
Sunday, November 24, 2019
Sunday, December 1, 2019
Sunday, December 8, 2019
Sunday, December 15, 2019
Sunday, December 22, 2019
Sunday, December 29, 2019
```